# $\sigma_0(n)=\varphi(n)$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

$$\sigma_0(n)=\varphi(n)$$
for positive integer $n$. For which $n$ does equality hold? I have found a few numbers  $(3, 8, 10, 18 ...)$.

Comment: I do not think there is an easy pattern for your equation.

Comment: Observation: if coprime integers $m$ and $n$ satisfy the equation, then so does $mn$.

Comment: Please recall what $\sigma_0$ and $\varphi$ are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of divisors of $n$ is at most $2\sqrt{n}$ while the number of numbers coprime to $n$ is at least equal to the number of primes in the range $(n/2,n)$ (when $n$ is prime the reasoning is different but it is still very much true).

We can give a lower bound on the number of primes in the range $(n/2,n)$ by using lower and upper bounds for the prime counting function, some of which can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function).

For example, we have that for $x\geq 55$ we have $\frac{x}{\ln(x)+2}< \pi(x) < \frac{x}{\ln(x) - 4}$.

It follows that the number of primes in the range $(n/2,n)$ for $n\geq 110$ is at least $\frac{n}{\ln(n) + 2} - \frac{n/2}{\ln(n/2)-4}$ which we can just bound by $\frac{n}{3\ln(n)}$.

For what values do we have $\frac{n}{3\ln (n)} > 2\sqrt{n}$? It appears for all $n>2109$.

So it follows we must only check all numbers in the range $1,\dots,2109$.

I did this and the only solutions are $1,3,8,10,18,24,30$ (actually I checked up to $10^5$ just in case I was careless in some of the bounds)

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of such $n$ is called [A020488](https://oeis.org/A020488). We have exactly the following $7$ values
$$
1, 3, 8, 10, 18, 24, 30.
$$
A reason is also given: "This sequence is complete because $\tau(n) < n^{2/3}$ for all $n$ except a few small numbers, whereas $\phi(n) > n/(\exp(\gamma) \cdot \log(\log(n)) + 3/(\log(\log(n)))$ for $n > 2$.